# UITableView + UIscrollView + UIcollectionView Point Me To The Right Direction

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have The following situation.
I have a HUGE amount of data split in sections.
The user only sees  5. But when he/she clicks See All (Section header button). 
I push another tableview with the rest of the data for that section.

What I would Like to do is the following: 
Instead of pushing each section seperatly I would like to push ( if Possible ) all sections In a form of scrollview and when the user scrolls the tableview data will change below.

---

```
                        <----->
```

SECTION 1 -----------------SECTION2-------------------SECTION 3
-------------------------------|------------------------------------

I would also like for the tableview to have the same functionality ( when scroll horizontal) like 2 scrollviews scrolling the same content.

What is the best way to implement - JUST POINT ME TO THE RIGHT DIRECTION

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation I suppose that you can follow this solution :

1,Use UIScrollView as your root view(or rootViewController,whatever you want);

2,Just make your UITableViewControllers & UICollectionViewControllers as ChildViewControllers in UIScrollViewController;

3,Add tableViews and collectionView as subViews into root scrollView;

By the way,there are many open source projects can handle these situation.Here are some examples:

https://github.com/monsieurje/ICViewPager

https://github.com/daria-kopaliani/DAPagesContainer

Maybe this answer doesn't help you to solve your problem perfectly,but I think it would help you to get more inspiration.Enjoy it.